# How do you draw a boxplot without specifying x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The base graphics can nicely plot a boxplot using a simple command

```
data(mtcars)
boxplot(mtcars$mpg)
```

[image]

But `qplot` requires y axis. How can I achieve with qplot the same like base graphics boxplot and not get this error?

```
qplot(mtcars$mpg,geom='boxplot')
Error: stat_boxplot requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to provide some dummy value to `x`. `theme()` elements are used to remove x axis title and ticks.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=factor(0),mpg))+geom_boxplot()+
   theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

Or using `qplot()` function:

```
qplot(factor(0),mpg,data=mtcars,geom='boxplot')
```

[image]

Comment: I see. So the qplot would be  qplot(factor(0),mtcars$mpg,geom='boxplot')

Answer (score 3):

you can set the x aesthetics to `factor(0)` and tweak the appearance by removing unwanted labels:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(0), mpg)) +
    geom_boxplot() + 
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL) +
    xlab(NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: While this might answer the question, please explain your answer and perhaps show an example image

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `latticeExtra`, to mix `boxplot` syntax and `ggplot2-like` theme:

```
bwplot(~mpg,data =mtcars,
        par.settings = ggplot2like(),axis=axis.grid)
```

[image]